# DualBoot System (Windows/Linux) with hardware drivers installed on Windows

Tags: linux, drivers, windows, dual-boot

I'm thinking of making a Dual-Boot system, just for installing some hardware drivers that aren't available for Linux (neither are open-source alternatives). Will the Linux environment be able to configure the hardware using the drivers that are installed on the Windows?

Comment: R u really a C programmer? Your question sounds almost like a bad joke. As a programmer you must know that different OSes have different userspace and kernel level APIs, so there's no way their device drivers could be compatible.  Even Unix OSes like FreeBSD, NetBSD and OpenBSD all have different drivers models though all have "BSD" in their names and they are all POSIX certified. MacOS is also a BSD OS.

Comment: Well, I know it, but I just wanted to get an answer. Maybe I'm wrong. Besides, the name's from a project I'm writing for my undergraduate. So don't expect much from me. That's why I'm an exhausted programmer, not an entusiast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really face the Problem that Linux does not recognize your Hardware you could run Linux in a VM (virtual machine) from Windows.

This will abstract hardware drivers to virtual Windows device drivers that are known to Linux.

You could either use **Hyper-V** or **VirtualBox**. For security reasons I would advise Hyper-V.

Since Hyper-V ist a Level 0 Hypervisor it is propably a little faster, and you do not leave the Micrsoft world.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I was thinking. I didn't know any other VM, except from VirtualBox. The reason that I wanted to avoid using it, is because I want to be able to connect to the internet (I know that is not safe doing that from a VM and it depends on where you browse) and that I prefer Linux over Windows. But, if that's the case and I don't find anything else, I will do it.

Answer (score 0):

In a dual-boot system, only one OS runs at a time.  When you are  booted into Linux, only the Linux kernel will be loaded, which only loads Linux modules/drivers. When in Windows, the Windows OS/kernel will only load Windows drivers.

You may consider two options:

- Run [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/about) to run a Linux distribution for development from within your Windows environment. This is the approach I use. It will get you most (but perhaps not all, depending on your use case) of the Linux development environment inside Windows. WSL2 actually runs under a subset of Hyper-V, but does not require Hyper-V, so it can run using any Windows version.
- Run Linux inside a virtual machine in Windows using Hyper-V, VirtualBox, or equivalent. Note that Hyper-V does require Windows Professional or higher .

Comment: I didn't know of the first option. Sounds interesting. I'll check it. Thank you.

Comment: @ExhaustedCProgrammer It's what a lot of students seem to be using for class projects like this. That said, there are some caveats you may run into, but you will typically find the answer here on the Stack sites (mostly Super User).

Comment: Oh, and if you have the latest Windows 20 update that came out in the last few weeks (21H1), it's as easy as `wsl --install ubuntu`

Comment: That's pretty good. I'll try it in another device. Unfortunately, I don't use Windows on my laptop. I'll have to install them for the second one. But, I still don't understand how to install it. Do I have to run Windows or do I install that as a software layer below the OS and then I choose the OS?

Comment: @ExhaustedCProgrammer Ah, right.  In that case, none of the VM solutions (nor WSL) are really going to solve your root problem, since they are all going to continue to rely on the Linux drivers.  The Windows VM under that will use Windows drivers, but for virtual hardware exposed by the Linux drivers themselves.